# Why does playing a html5 video result in high cpu usage by libpepflashplayer.so?

Tags: linux, cpu, flash, youtube, html5

When I play a HTML5 video on youtube (both https://www.youtube.com/html5 and a right click on the video show that HTML5 is used) with chromium the cpu usage goes to 100% on all cores caused by libpepflashplayer.so.

Is youtube just pretending to be using HTML5 and actually uses flash or is there something else going on (i.e. what tests can I perform to troubleshoot)?

High cpu load is also the case with firefox, but in that case there is no separate process for the flash-plugin, so I have no indication whether flash is involved.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior on my system

Comment: Was the video a live-stream or something?  AFAIK youtube still uses flash for that and a few other things here and there.  It may also get used if your browser/system doesn't have the correct codecs or something.

Comment: @Zoredache No, it happens an all videos. And as I said, if I right click on the video I get a menu where the last entry is "About the HTML5 player", still libpepflashplayer.so is used. This combination confuses me. Is it possible that the actual player is flash-player and this menu is still in use?